# Python multiprocessing pool making copies of argument list

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am using the map method of a multiprocessing.Pool object to process a very large (>2gb) list of arguments. Based on my memory usage when I run my script, each worker seems to be making a local copy of this list. Because of this, I'm using far more memory than I ought to be using, so what should I be using instead to handle this case?

EDIT: Added code for illustration. I have hundreds of video frames of cell imaging data and I'm using a blob detection algorithm to identify their centers and radii. It is certainly an example of an embarrassingly parallel problem.

```
frames = load_frames(file_vid)
with mp.Pool() as p:
    cells = p.map(frame_cells, frames)
with open(file_cells, "wb") as f:
    pk.dump(cells, f)
```

Comment: Yes, this is how `multiprocessing` *works*. It does not share state, it creates *multiple processes*.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you load all frames at once. What you should be doing instead is to load frame by frame and feed these into `imap`. This way your memory footprint will remain small while allowing to use multiprocessing.

Here's a code that illustrates the concept:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools
import time

def g():
    for el in range(100):
        yield el

def square(x):
    return x*x

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    r = list(pool.imap(square, g()))
```

Replace `g()` with your code that *yields* video frames, while `square` is your processing function.

Comment: This still requires copying the data in each process. And `imap` is pointless if you are just going to call `list` on it...

Comment: Each process gets **different** piece of data - and that's the point. You call list to get all results. If you like, you can just write it to file, upload or whatever is that you want to do.

Comment: Yes, that is also how `map` works, it just has *returns* a list. The problem here is that, as you state, the OP has already `frames = load_frames(file_vid)`, so each process is going to *require a copy* (the same case here, `imap` doesn't change that). We don't know if creating something like `def g()` is feasible here. That is the crux of the matter